# Beamer blocks and itemize

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, beamerposter

I am using the [`beamerposter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter) package and I have adjusted the beamerblock so that the columns line up and have correct spacing.  However itemize now runs from the very edge of the block on the left to very edge on the right.  I can solve the left margin with:

```
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{2.5em}
```

but cannot seem to do anything about the right margin.  Any suggestions?  My block is set as:

```
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \vskip.75ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1cm,sep=.75ex]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{block end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `minipage` to achieve that with `minipage`-s or `hspace` for padding.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \vskip.75ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1cm,sep=.75ex]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{block end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\usepackage{beamerposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}

\addtolength{\leftmargini}{2.5cm}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{-2.5cm}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\hsize}
\addtolength{\mylength}{-5cm}
\begin{minipage}{2.5cm}\hfill\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\mylength}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{2.5cm}\hfill\end{minipage}

\hspace{2.5cm}
\begin{minipage}{\mylength}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```